# C# Custom click event that not inherit from Control

Tags: c#

Can i implement a custom click event that raise when user click on my object.

My object doesn't inherit any class but it has a Location Width Height properties.

Question is : i don't know how code that when i create MyObj subscribe to click event.

```
public delegate void CusEventHandler(object sender, CusEventArgs e);
public class MyObject
{
    private Point location;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public event CusEventHandler Click;
    public MyObject(Point loc, int w, int h)
    {
        this.location = loc;
        this.width= w;
        this.height= h;
    }
    protected virtual void OnClick(CusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Click != null)
        {
            Click(this, e);
        }
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public MyObject myObj;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myObj = new (new Point(5,5),100,100);
        myObj.Click+= new CusEventHandler(myObj_click);
    }
    private void myObj_click(object sender,CusEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Your object is not a visual component.  I don't think anyone can see it to click on it.  I think you need to inherit from: System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Comment: Why don't you just inherit from something that provides the functionality you are looking for? That is the whole point in inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You are recommenced inheriting your class from Control, so that hit testing is already done for you.
See also [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172866/winforms-customcontrol-hit-test)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't replicate the logic used in clickable controls like `System.Windows.Controls.Button` then you can't do that. You must inherit from a control which provides a `Click`-event. This is why there is inheritance and most of the controls offer you to inherit from them.

Additonally, if your control did inherit from a base class like `System.Windows.Controls.Control` you can't use it in Windows either.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx).